# Creating and returning a new array in C

Tags: c

So I'm getting an error of "incompatible types in assignment" and have no idea why. I'm returning a new pointer to the array back in the main function is what I'm trying to do as I'm increasing the size of the array by one.

***NOTE***: This is the fixed code!

Here's my code:

```
void maxHeap(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int sizeOfHeap);
void extractMax(int *theHeap, int sizeOfHeap);
int *insertKey(int *theHeap, int theKey, int sizeOfHeap);
void heapKeyInc(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int theKey);
void changeKey(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int theKey, int sizeOfHeap);
int *deleteKey(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int sizeOfHeap);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE *inputFile; 

    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Could not open file or it could not be found.\n");
        return 1; 
    }else{
        inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }

    int sizeOfHeap = -1, i, count=1;

    fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &sizeOfHeap);

    int *theHeap , tempItem;
    theHeap = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeOfHeap+1);

    for(i=1; i<=sizeOfHeap;i++){
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &tempItem);
        theHeap[i]= tempItem;
    }

    if(sizeOfHeap == -1){
        printf("Heap was not initialized, please ensure an integer is the first item in the file.\n");
        return 2;
    }else{
        for(i=(count/2)+1;i > 0;i--){
            maxHeap(theHeap, i, sizeOfHeap);
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("The Heap:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=sizeOfHeap;i++){
        printf("theHeap[%d] = %d\n", i, theHeap[i]);
    }

    char *tempString, theCommand;
    tempString = malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    int temp1, temp2;

    printf("\n\n");

    while(fscanf(inputFile, "%s", tempString) != EOF){
        //printf("tempString = %s\n", tempString);
        theCommand = (*tempString);
        //printf("theCommand = %d\n",theCommand);
        switch(theCommand){
            case 'E': 
                printf("Extract command!\n");
                extractMax(theHeap, sizeOfHeap);
                sizeOfHeap--;
                printf("The Heap:\n");
                break;
            case 'I':
                printf("Insert command!\n");
                fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &temp1);
                theHeap = insertKey(theHeap, temp1, sizeOfHeap);
                sizeOfHeap++;
                break;
            case 'C':
                printf("Change key command!\n");
                fscanf(inputFile, "%d %d", &temp1, &temp2);
                changeKey(theHeap, temp1, temp2, sizeOfHeap);
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("Delete key command!\n");
                fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &temp1);
                theHeap = deleteKey(theHeap, temp1, sizeOfHeap);
                sizeOfHeap--;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Not valid\n");
                break;
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("\n\nThe Heap:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=sizeOfHeap;i++){
        printf("theHeap[%d] = %d\n", i, theHeap[i]);
    }


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void maxHeap(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int sizeOfHeap){
    int leftChild, rightChild, largest, tempData; 

    leftChild = 2*theIndex; 
    rightChild = 2*theIndex + 1;


    if(leftChild <= sizeOfHeap && theHeap[leftChild] > theHeap[theIndex]){
        largest = leftChild;
    }else{
        largest = theIndex;
    }

    if(rightChild <= sizeOfHeap && theHeap[rightChild] > theHeap[largest]){

        largest = rightChild; 
    }

    if(largest != theIndex){
        tempData = theHeap[theIndex];
        theHeap[theIndex] = theHeap[largest];
        theHeap[largest] = tempData;

        maxHeap(theHeap, largest, sizeOfHeap);
    }

    return;
}

void extractMax(int *theHeap, int sizeOfHeap){
    if(sizeOfHeap < 1){
        printf("No data in the heap!\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Extract please!\n");
    int max = theHeap[1];
    theHeap[1] = theHeap[sizeOfHeap];
    sizeOfHeap--;
    maxHeap(theHeap, 1, sizeOfHeap);

    return;
}

int *insertKey(int *theHeap, int theKey, int sizeOfHeap){
    sizeOfHeap++;
    int *newHeap = malloc(sizeof(int)*(sizeOfHeap+1)), i; 
    for(i=1;i<sizeOfHeap;i++){
        newHeap[i] = theHeap[i];
    }
    newHeap[sizeOfHeap] = -1; 
    heapKeyInc(newHeap, sizeOfHeap, theKey);

    return newHeap;
}

void heapKeyInc(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int theKey){
    int temp;

    if(theKey < theHeap[theIndex]){
        printf("New key is smaller than current.\n");
        return;
    }

    theHeap[theIndex] = theKey;
    while(theIndex > 1 && theHeap[(theIndex/2)+1] < theHeap[theIndex]){
        temp = theHeap[theIndex];
        theHeap[theIndex] = theHeap[(theIndex/2)+1];
        theHeap[(theIndex/2)+1] = temp;
        theIndex = (theIndex/2)+1;
    }
}

void changeKey(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int theKey, int sizeOfHeap){
    theHeap[theIndex] = theKey;
    maxHeap(theHeap, theIndex, sizeOfHeap);

    return;
}

int *deleteKey(int *theHeap, int theIndex, int sizeOfHeap){
    if(theIndex > sizeOfHeap){
        printf("The index is not in the heap.\n");
        return theHeap;
    }else{
        int *newHeap, i, tempIndex;
        sizeOfHeap--;
        newHeap =  malloc(sizeof(int)*(sizeOfHeap+1));

        changeKey(theHeap, theIndex, theHeap[sizeOfHeap+1], sizeOfHeap);

        for(i=1;i<=sizeOfHeap;i++){
            newHeap[i] = theHeap[i];
        }

        return newHeap;
    }    
}
```

So, I'll leave up the original story of the problem. The code above is now with the fixed code (and does work with creating a heap and maintaining it). So the moral of the story is, whenever you need to manipulate an array size as you delete elements, remove or extract, it is always best to initialize the array (your variable) to a pointer of whatever type you desire. Then get the memory for the array by mallocing the size of the variable type and multiplying it by the size of your array.

Note: I added 1 to my initialization so I could refer to the index at position starting at 1 to N elements, this allows me to skip over the 0 element which is never used.

Thanks for all the help to catch my errors and helping me realize I shouldn't listen to people who tell me not to worry about the warnings as it caused problems when trying to create new arrays. I really do enjoy the help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full error trace so we can determine which line has the error?

Comment: `|69|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'int[(unsigned int)(sizeOfHeap + 1)]' from type 'int *'`

Comment: It's "main.c:69: error: incompatible types in assignment"

Comment: What's going on here? `int *newHeap = malloc(sizeOfHeap+1), i;`

Comment: I'm creating a pointer to an integer type and making it size of the size of the heap + 1. Also I have updated the code to include the log that was given after trying to compile.

Comment: Here: `maxHeap(&theHeap, i, sizeOfHeap);` `theHeap` is type `int *`, `maxHeap()` expects a `int *`, but you pass `&theHeap`, which is type `int **`. Just do `maxHeap(theHeap, i, sizeOfHeap);`, and in all the other places, too. You're using `&` way too much.

Comment: But if I do it that way, will it update the information in the array back in the main function?

Comment: Perhaps instead of writing `int theHeap[sizeOfHeap+1]` you should write `int *theHeap = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizeOfHeap + 1));`

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the warnings.

Comment: You can't assign to an array like this: `theHeap = insertKey(&theHeap, temp1, sizeOfHeap);`, and here, `fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &temp1);` `&temp1` is a `char *`, but you're using `%d` which expects an `int`. Lots and lots of basic errors here, all of which your compiler should warn you about.

Comment: I have updated the code and the rest of my question. I have fix the array to be initialize properly using pointers instead of an array. I have also fixed passing of the variables to the functions as well to include the proper way. Thanks for all your help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: In the 'I' case, what is expected to be in the input file after the 'I'? If you are expecting an integer, why don't you just declare `temp1` as an `int`? The `insertKey` function expects the second parameter to be an `int` and you're using fscanf to read an `int`. The only issue is the `temp1` declaration. Will the file contain something like this: `I123`?

Comment: The I case has a proceeding integer which is regarded as temp1 (it should have been an int value don't know why I did that) and is inserted into the array.

Comment: So does simply changing `temp1` to an `int` fix it?

Comment: Ya, it fixed that warning. Haha. I'm almost done fixing it all so hopefully I can show the completed program. I shouldn't have listened to the person who told me to use an array and not care about the warnings.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to all those that helped. I have updated my code with the correct answer and hope that this may help other people when dealing with dynamic data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because of this line `fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &temp1);`. The function scans an int but then store into a char which may cause an overflow